# Using python to select from multiple select boxes with the same name

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use python and selenium chromedriver to make selections on the first of two select boxes with the same name.  I know, I know, it's bad website design but I don't have control over that.

I would like to select the first one and make three consecutive selection (each opens a child webpage).

Any hints/tips/suggestions welcomed.
Thanks in advance.

both have name="select" as an identifier.

Once I get it right I will consecutively select each of three selections and each selection will open a child webpage.

Comment: show your code trials and the html structure of web elements and errors you getting., please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This is what I get when I inspect the element:

<select name="select" onchange="window.open(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,'_blank')">…</select>

I don't have any code yet (because I don't know how to proceed).

Comment: please read the link provided in above comment.it is like help to help your self. unless you provide good reproducible understandable example no/few response to your question will get. Do add all necessary things in ***question***